# UITableView rowHeight UITableViewAutomaticDimension cell wrong height after first load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a UITableViewCell subclass that has two labels of variable height.  AFAIK, the autolayout constraints are correct.  The first time the cell is rendered in the table it's correct, but any subsequent rendering is blown out too tall.  Even after the parent view controller is deallocated!  It literally requires an app restart to go back to normal.

I've tried clearing text of the labels in an override of prepareForReuse in the cell class.

// viewDidLoad
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To support dynamic layout with textview, a height constraint is needed and that needs to be updated in `layoutSubviews` method(you need to subclass `UITextview`).

In addition to this, you need to make sure you have a UITextview bottom constraint with cell's contentView.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your bottom constraint of `UILabel` is getting increased. Check if you are updating the bottom constraint constant value.